# How to fix a mdb file?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have a MDB file that can't be opened. It seems like it's corrupted. Is there a best practice how to fix that?

I've already tried this tool
StellarPhoenixAccessDatabaseRepair
but it didn't help.

I need to make this file works again...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [these](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html) methods for repairing corrupted database. If database cannot be opened at all, even with pressed Shift, try to import database objects to new database.